# Class annotation causes ClassNotFound exception

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

I am using Serialization at Server and De-serialization at android client as communication protocol.

The POJO used is defined as

```
@EntityTag(uri = "/t.do", layout_id = "teacher")
public class Teacher extends UIEntity{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = (long)0x000010;
  public Teacher() throws UIEntityFormatException {super();}

  @ViewTag(view_id = "t_name")
  private String name;
  @ViewTag(view_id = "t_sur_name")
  private String surName;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getSurName() {
    return surName;
  }

  public void setSurName(String surName) {
    this.surName = surName;
  }
}
```

The EntityTag and ViewTag are defined separately.

Code used to write Object in Server is

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      try {
        final Teacher t = new Teacher();
        t.setName("jacob");
        t.setSurName("bush");
        final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(t);
        oos.flush();
      } catch (UIEntityFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

and Code used at client for receive this

```
      final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
      ret = (Result) objectInputStream.readObject();
      objectInputStream.close();
```

AndroidHttpClient is used. and an ClassNotFound for EntityTag.class is throw when client is run.

Teacher, UIEntity, and annotations are put in a Module called protocol and Client Server modules has dependency on that(I am using Intellij IDEA 13) I can not figure out what caused the Exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, Nick.

I figure out what went wrong.

Java Serialization was an old mechanism create decade before annotation. I guess that is why Default serialization/de-serialization does not handle problem properly.

when I use byte[] read from server and put that into a Plain text file I can see annotation has been defined pretty much as an Class. I suppose that is why JVM tries to load this annotation (which could be totally ignored since it residents at both server and client side), So I tried to over write readObject and writeObject method of Serialaizable classes. no more annotation classes represented and problem solved.

It is not a configuration problem. but we should be careful when deal with combination of old and new techniques.

Thanks for your help anyway